# convert decimal(19,4) to string format in sql query using c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to convert a 100.0000 to 0010000 and 15 to 01500 . I tried these below steps but not to luck.

```
String.Format("{0:0000000}", pcnCharge); PCn Charge :100.0000(decimal 19,4)
String.Format("{0:00000}", courtFee); int 15
```

Comment: Please make sure you mark the answer that you used from your last question as accepted when you are ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to multiply the values so as to shift the decimal point, for example:

```
String.Format("{0:0000000}", pcnCharge * 100); 
String.Format("{0:00000}", courtFee * 100);
```

As I mentioned in the other answer, you can also use the "D#" format string for this:

```
String.Format("{0:D7}", pcnCharge * 100); 
String.Format("{0:D5}", courtFee * 100);
```

And, if you want to be "truly correct", you can specify the `100` as a decimal using `100M`

```
String.Format("{0:D7}", pcnCharge * 100M); 
String.Format("{0:D5}", courtFee * 100M);
```

Comment: error `Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.` i get this error when i use this. String.Format("{0:D7}, bat.PCN_Charge * 100") or any 3 statments

Comment: Your double quotes are incorrect: `String.Format("{0:D7}, bat.PCN_Charge * 100")` should be `String.Format("{0:D7}", bat.PCN_Charge * 100)` - note the last double quote has changed position

Comment: String.Format("{0:D7}", (bat.PCN_Charge) * 100) + i have an error at bat.pcn where it says bat does not exist in current context but it is reference of a table in my sql query.

Comment: You'll need to ask that as a new question - the comment section isn't the place for it. The above answer will answer your original specific question, if you are happy with it please mark it as accepted (and the one from your last question) and ask a new question with your new problem.